# Best Data Access Technology in MVC4 and MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in confusion about the data access technology in mvc4 whether we should use Entity Framework or Linq or something else which is better than this ?

I have research much in this topic and not satisfied with all.?So can you help me about this with proper  Detail?

Comment: Should go with LINQ using Repository Pattern

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Thanks...have you any link with Linq using Repository pattern tutorials

Comment: This question is very broad and opinion-based. Do you mean LINQ in general or LINQ-to-SQL? How do you define "best"? Entity Framework and NHibernate are both great. Use whichever you prefer. If you don't know which, use EntityFramework. I don't recommend LINQ-to-SQL (but I do recommend LINQ always and forever).

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fba912/generic-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-linq/

Comment: @RowanFreeman Sir i was in a interview last monday and i have worked in linq for 1 year and the interviewer just told me that linq is the worst as its performance is so bad ..and i was speechless to him :(

Comment: @NeerajMehta it is not if used with your brain

Answer (score 1):

The question will have answers upon user based opinions and experience.

This is what my personal recommendation is Model:

Take this as a Tree View Structure

```
1. Controller
   2. ActionMethod //call the desired Factories
      3.1 View Factory //to get data in DB
      3.2 Domain Factory //to set data in DB
          4. Services //Interface for Caching and top operations
             5. Repositories //Contains on CRUD Operations
```

Inside the Repositories I would prefer LINQ-to-Entities rather than LINQ-to-SQL.

**[A great way of UNIT OF WORK PATTERN is being explained here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)**